# Ban Indexable Types in TypeScript

Tags: regex, typescript, yaml, tslint

I am trying to search for a tslint rule in `tslint.yml` that will flag out any use of [Indexable Types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#indexable-types) (e.g. `{ [key: string] : string }`) to instead use TypeScript Records (e.g. `Record<string, string>`), but with no luck at the moment.

I came across a tslint rule known as [Ban-Types](https://palantir.github.io/tslint/rules/ban-types/), which bans types that match a given regex. I have tried the following

**`tslint.yml`**

```yaml
  ban-types: [
    true,
    [ "{\s*\[\s*(\S+)\s*:\s*(.+)\s*\]\s*:\s*(.+)\s*}",
      "Do not use indexable types (i.e. { [index: A] : B } ). Use Record<A, B> instead." ],
  ]
```

but it gives this error:

```
unknown escape sequence at line 23, column 10:
        [ "{\s*\[\s*(\S+)\s*:\s*(.+)\s*\]\s*: ... 
             ^ in /path/to/tslint.yml
```

I tried again with the following regex:

**`tslint.yml`**

```yaml
  ban-types: [
    true,
    [ "\\{\\s*\\[\\s*(\\S+)\\s*:\\s*(.+)\\s*\\]\\s*:\\s*(.+)\\s*\\}",
      "Do not use indexable types (i.e. { [index: A] : B } ). Use Record<A, B> instead." ],
  ]
```

which did not throw any exceptions, but were unable to detect indexable types.

The implementation of the rule can be found [here](https://github.com/palantir/tslint/blob/master/src/rules/banTypesRule.ts), if it helps.

Comment: The regex is anchored by default in the code you refer to, hence you need  `".*\\{\\s*\\[\\s*(\\S+)\\s*:\\s*(.+)\\s*\\]\\s*:\\s*(.+)\\s*\\}.*"`

Answer (score 0):

Does this work for you?

```regex
    \{\s*\[\s*\w+\s*:\s*\w+\s*\]\s*:\s*\w*\s*\}
```

[image: regex explanation]

Comment: Doesn't work, it throws an exception "unknown escape sequence". Escaping twice (i.e. `\\{`) does prevent an error but it still does not detect.